# How can I filter a pandas series to only elements that are numeric characters 0-9 and grab the indices of those elements?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I filter a pandas series to only elements that are numbers (0-9) and grab the indices of those elements?

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data = np.array(['g', "1", 'e', "5", 'h'])
df = pd.Series(data, index=['ee1', 'ee2', 'ee3', 'ee4', 'ee5'])
```

For example, I want to access `ee2` and `ee4` as `['ee2', 'ee4']`.

Comment: Any attempt you have made?

Comment: Im stuck on the filtering portion. If I can get help with that, I can grab the names using `df.index`.

Comment: ,you need to know about boolean masking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[df.str.isnumeric()].index
```

Output:

```
Index(['ee2', 'ee4'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I would give an explanation, but it seems fairly self evident. Plus, who can deny the beauty of a short one-liner!

Comment: if you want it as a list, you can append .to_list() to the end of it

Comment: I'd slice directly the Index `df.index[df.str.isnumeric()]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Boolean Masking will do the Job for you.
to understand run the below statement

```
 df.str.isdigit()
Out[240]:
ee1    False
ee2     True
ee3    False
ee4     True
ee5    False
dtype: bool
```

Lets pass this mask to the series

```
df[df.str.isdigit()]                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[239]:                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ee2    1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
ee4    5                                                                                                                                                                                                        
dtype: object
```

you can also use the below code snipped suggested by @mozway

```
df.index[df.str.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: OP wanted the indices! :-)

Comment: Hint is given, Op can definitely figure it out now how to extract index :)

Comment: Then technically speaking, the answer is incorrect, and only a very slight adjustment on the already presented answer.

Comment: @S3DEV How is it incorrect?, there may be n solution for the same question with little adjustment :)